# Is there a way to change sudo mount read-only to read-write?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, sudo, mount, nfs

I mounted some data from the server to my Colab Notebook with the command:

```py
!sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 something.com:/ data/
```

This will create me a data directory with read-only permissions. However, I need to write some new files to this directory. I tried changing the permissions of this directory with the command:

```py
!chmod -R 777 /content/data
```

However, I think this is inefficient, as it will need to go through all the files and subdirectories, which will waste tons of time when the data is huge. Is there any other way to change folder permissions from read-only to read-write during mounting? Thank you!

Comment: Does `sudo mount -o remount,rw /data` not work (where `/data` is the mountpoint)? Or just mount it `rw` to start with. But it's not really programming related so should probably be better asked over at https://superuser.com.

Comment: This is better asked on superuser.com or serverfault.com. Its an OS question, not a programming question.

Comment: Changing all of the files to everybody writes is a security disaster.

Comment: I know, right? Iterating through each file is a nightmare. All I want is to create a new file in this directory.

Comment: If your 777 thing works, then you are already mounted read-write and your identity on the remote has the right to make that change. If you can't create a file in a specific directory, then you could temporarily change the rights bits on that directory (user write should be enough).

Comment: It worked. However, it sucks, I have 10Tb of data, using this way would be a nightmare.